# efficient way to check if a group of letters in a string is a variable?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, variables, string-literals

I am trying to write a code to print music scales. I cannot use a list or array type of structure (school reasons). here's what i have so far:

```
public class Musicarum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double buildNum = 0.01;
        
        //**************************************************************************************
        int a = 1, bb = 2, b = 3, c = 4, db = 4, d = 5, eb = 6, e = 7, f = 8, gb = 9, ab = 10;
        //**************************************************************************************
```

then further in the code it will, once you select where you want to go, it should print a scale. right now i am on major scales:

```
if(answer.equals("scales")) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to see a major or a minor scale?");
                String scale = input.nextLine();
                scale = scale.toLowerCase();
                if(scale.equals("major"));
                System.out.println("What Scale would you like to see?");
                scale = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("The scale you would like to see is made of the notes: " + scale.charAt(0));
}}
```

my current problem is in the line above last where i am printing the scale. I am wondering if it is possible to check the string `scale` and see if the words inside correspond to a variable that i predefined. i then want to be able to use the number value that i assigned to the variable. I have tried using the unicode value of the first character the user types, but i don't know how to use that to match to one of my int variables. I have also looked into setting up something similar to a python dictionary, but I'm completely at a loss for how to do that right now. any help? trying to do this without using 4000 nested if statements and 157 variables for each scale.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. But note: please don't come back to then change the subject of the question. If you have another problem on your way, then first do research, and if that doesn't help, feel free to write another new question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java isnt a dynamic language, so taking a user string and "translating" that into a variable name is (albeit possible) extremely burdensome (and a very advanced topic).

The straight forward answer to your problem is to use the **Map** structure (maps are Java's equivalent of python's dicts). A quick example:

```
Map<String, Integer> scaleByName = new HashMap<>();
scaleByName.put("a", 1); 
scaleByName.put("bb", 2); ...
```

Then you can use calls like `scaleByName.get(someStringComingFromUserInput)` to *map* the string key to its Integer value. There is plenty of [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) that tells you more how to use maps.

Comment: thank you %1000 you are a saint. I will look into maps and see if i can fix this problem and will probably edit my post when I do (or don't)